# How do I create a session between an Android Application and Django Rest-Auth through Retrofit?

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, retrofit, django-rest-auth

I am able to do the initial log in to the server and get the token, but when I try to do another request I get the HTTP error 403, so I am not actually being authenticated.

When I go through the browser or the android application, this is the key that I am getting when I log in.

{
    "key": "64ea43a78fa18da19364d2d0ae5a12371e5d0ee2"
}

Is there anything that I can do with this key using retrofit? I have tried using the header "Authorization" and following with the token.

Here is my RestClient interface:

```
public interface RestClient {

    @POST ("rest-auth/login/")
    Call<Token> login(
            @Body Login body
    );

    @GET ("v2/users/{user}/")
    Call<List<CustomUser>> getUser(
            @Header("Authorization") String token,
            @Path("user") String user
    );
```

Here is the AsyncTask which will perform the requests to the server. The authenticateUser gives me an HTTP response of 200, but the syncUser gives 403.

```
public class ActionSync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
RestClient client;
IData activity;
private static String token;

public ActionSync(Context context) {
    activity = (IData) context;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://" + params[2] + ":" + params[3] + "/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    client = retrofit.create(RestClient.class);

    //Authenticate the user.
    authenticateUser(params[0], params[1]);

    //Once the authentication has been completed, we can now move on the syncing data.
    syncUser(params[0]);




    //If we get to the end without any errors, then return true. This means that the sync is complete.
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean loggedIn) {
    super.onPostExecute(loggedIn);
}

public void authenticateUser(String username, String password){
    //First, we must log into the server given our credentials. Otherwise, we will not be able to get any data.
    Login login = new Login(username, password);

    Call<Token> call = client.login(login);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.v("ActionSync", "Login was successful");
                token = response.body().getKey();
            } else {
                Log.v("ActionSync", "Login was unsuccessful");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Token> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("ActionSync", "Error occurred during login");
        }
    });
}

public void syncUser(String username){
    Call<List<CustomUser>> call = client.getUser(token, username);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CustomUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<CustomUser>> call, Response<List<CustomUser>> response) {
            Log.v("ActionSync", "The response from get user: " + response.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<CustomUser>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("ActionSync", "No response from get user");
        }
    });
}

public interface IData {
}
```

}